# gzclient crash with heightmap

Tags: ogre

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi

I obtain an ogre exception each time I try to use an heightmap
e.g., using

```
gzserver -u worlds/heightmap.world
```

the `gzclient` crash with the following output

```
Qt has caught an exception thrown from an event handler. Throwing exceptions from an event handler is not supported in Qt. You must reimplement QApplication::notify() and catch all exceptions there.

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Ogre::Exception'
what():  OGRE EXCEPTION(2:InvalidParametersException): Named constants have not been initialised, perhaps a compile error. in GpuProgramParameters::_findNamedConstantDefinition at /build/buildd/ogre-1.7.4/OgreMain/src/OgreGpuProgramParams.cpp (line 1425)
Aborted
```

I'm running Gazebo 1.4 by repository binary packages on a xubuntu 12.04 in *virtual machine*.
In particular I've tried both vmware and virtualBox, both with the same results.

I've found online other thread about similar problems, but I can't face a solution for my one.
Any suggestion? Avoid the usage of virtual machines? Compile and install from source code?

SImone

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1362/gzclient-crash-with-heightmap/) by [SImone](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/207/simone/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 33 on 2013-02-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

@SImone, I am not sure but probably your problem could be related to: http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/25/run-gazebo-in-virtualbox/

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Vaz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/171/daniel-vaz/) with karma: 305 on 2013-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1